# doseq Clojure returning nil, not accessing functions

Tags: clojure

What I'm trying to do is for every word in the sequence run each word through the function called `transform`, which will sort alphabetically and also change to lowercase.  But all I am getting back is `nil`??

I'm guessing I'm using `doseq` wrong but it looks fine? Can anyone give me some pointers?

```
(defn sort-string [s]
  (apply str (sort s)))

(defn transform [word x]
  (let [x (sort-string (str/lower-case word))]
    (prn word)
    (prn word)))

(doseq [dictionary '("one" "two" "three" "FouR" "wot" "Rheet" "nope" "#")]
  (transform dictionary))
```

Comment: doseq always returns nil

Comment: additionally, your transform function takes a second arg (named `x`), even though you never give it anything, and you're immediately re-binding `x` to the value of the return from `sort-string`.

Answer (score 3):

`doseq` is for doing side effects while iterating over a sequence of items. For example, put each item one-by-one on a queue:

```
(doseq [msg messages]
  (put-to-queue! msg))
```

It returns `nil` because it is intended to be used for side effects, not to compute some *value*.

To *transform* a *list of values* (which is what you are trying to do), you can use `for`, which has a similar syntax to `doseq`. You can also use `map`, `filter`, `sort`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`doseq` is only for side effects, you can use `for` instead if you want the results as a sequence, its syntax is the same as doseq.

```
(for [wordset '("one" "two" "three" "FouR" "wot" "Rheet" "nope" "#")]
  (transform wordset))
=> ("eno" "otw" "eehrt" "foru" "otw" "eehrt" "enop" "#")
```

Comment: yeah that for would be ideal, so would that call transform with wordset for ever string in wordset?   What i ideally want to do is pass the sorted word and orignal word into a map

Comment: `(into {} (for [wordset ...] ((juxt identity transform) wordset))` - this returns a key/value pair using transform for each wordset, then puts them all into a hash-map

Comment: or did you want a separate map for each word?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example :

```
(def words ["one" "two" "three" "FouR" "wot" "Rheet" "nope" "#"])
(sort (map clojure.string/lower-case words))
 ;; => ("#" "four" "nope" "one" "rheet" "three" "two" "wot")
```

Comment: Is it not possible to pass a function for every string? as it want to let x be the sorted version of word.   Eventually once i get that sorted i want to pass both sorted and original word into a map

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your `transform` function and your `doseq` expression. They suggest that you don't understand how information is passed around in a Clojure program:

- Arguments to a function are passed *by value*, and are completely
  unaffected by the evaluation.
- A `let` binding redefines the name. It doesn't assign to the
  existing one.
- The only information that comes out of a function is its return value
  (ignoring side-effects).

---

Your `transform` function

- doesn't use its `x` argument
- prints its `word` argument - twice - and returns `nil`.

And The `let` binding has no effect.

What you want is something like ...

```
(defn transform [word]
   (sort-string (clojure.string/lower-case word)))
```

or, more concisely,

```
 (def transform 
   (comp sort-string clojure.string/lower-case))
```

This returns the transformed string without the side-effect of printing it.

---

As others have explained, `doseq` is inappropriate. It always returns `nil`. Just ...

```
 (let [dictionary '("one" "two" "three" "FouR" "wot" "Rheet" "nope" "#")]
   (map transform dictionary))
```

... gives ...

```
("eno" "otw" "eehrt" "foru" "otw" "eehrt" "enop" "#")
```

Comment: There's been editing going on, as of when I wrote my answer transform was actually correct...